# Eclipse: how to find functions in .h that have no implementation in .cpp?

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt

How to find functions in `.h` files that have no implementation in `.cpp` files and never used?

Seems Eclipse give no warning or error if such functions present.

If it matters I'm using Eclipse `Version: 3.8.1` on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Eclipse gives no error if those functions are never used. I don't think there's an easy way to get a full list of all functions (including those in classes and structs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eclipse does have a checker for unused function declarations, which can be enabled in Preferences -> C/C++ -> Code Analysis, but it only checks function declarations in `.cpp` files, not header files.

Checkers can have options (that can be configured by clicking "Customize Selected..." on that preference page), and it may make sense to add an option to the "Unused function declaration" checker to check header files as well.

You could [file an issue](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=CDT) requesting that such an option be added.

If you're interested, you could also consider [contributing](https://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/contributing) a patch that implements such an option. It would be a relatively straightforward change to the [existing checker code](http://git.eclipse.org/c/cdt/org.eclipse.cdt.git/tree/codan/org.eclipse.cdt.codan.checkers/src/org/eclipse/cdt/codan/internal/checkers/UnusedSymbolInFileScopeChecker.java). I have some experience with this code, and I would be happy to mentor you (or anyone else) in making such a change.

Comment: Unless the OP calls dibs, I may be interested in working on such a patch. The offer of mentorship is very generous of you!  What kind of time commitment would something like this require?

Comment: @Travis: If you're familiar with Java, I'd say an hour to set up an Eclipse CDT development environment, and a couple of hours to make and test the change.

Comment: I normally just make a list of declared functions with Perl. And make a list of symbols with nm on object files, de-mangle, and then compare. It's not perfect, but quick and simple

Comment: @Travis: Since we haven't heard from the OP, if you're still interested I'd say go for it!

Comment: @HighCommander4 Great! I am familiar with Java. And that's actually significantly less time than I would've thought. So I should have enough free time on Monday to complete this that day itself. Any advice for how I would get started?

Comment: @Travis: The first step is to file the bug. The second step is to set up the development environment as described [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Getting_started_with_CDT_development). I'll post more guidance in the bug once you've filed it.

Comment: @HighCommander4 Ok! I'll see if I can get ball rolling tomorrow, then post the link to the bug report here.

Comment: @Travis: Hey, just wanted to follow up on this. I know account creation on Eclipse's Bugzilla is moderated right now due to high spam levels, are you perhaps having trouble getting an account created?